# What does the author mean by "door culture" in this context?

Tags: american-english, slang, meaning

What does the author mean by "door culture" in this context?  First-order effects I take to be a metaphor with economics.  However, I don't understand how to translate my understanding of "first-order effects" meaning the first derivative of a formula to "door culture".

> "[The Tragedy of the Conversational Commons](http://p2pfoundation.net/Tragedy_of_the_Commons)", by Clay Shirky
>
> Flaming is one of a class of economic problems known as The Tragedy of
>   the Commons. Briefly stated, the tragedy of the commons occurs when a
>   group holds a resource, but each of the individual members has an
>   incentive to overuse it. (The original essay used the illustration of
>   shepherds with common pasture. The group as a whole has an incentive
>   to maintain the long-term viability of the commons, but with each
>   individual having an incentive to overgraze, to maximize the value
>   they can extract from the communal resource.)
>
> In the case of mailing lists (and, again, other shared conversational
>   spaces), the commonly held resource is communal attention. The group
>   as a whole has an incentive to keep the signal-to-noise ratio high and
>   the conversation informative, even when contentious. Individual users,
>   though, have an incentive to maximize expression of their point of
>   view, as well as maximizing the amount of communal attention they
>   receive. It is a deep curiosity of the human condition that people
>   often find negative attention more satisfying than inattention, and
>   the larger the group, the likelier someone is to act out to get that
>   sort of attention.
>
> However, proposed responses to flaming have consistently steered away
>   from group-oriented solutions and towards personal ones. The logic of
>   collective action, alluded to above, rendered these personal solutions
>   largely ineffective. Meanwhile attempts at encoding social bargains
>   weren't attempted because of the twin forces of **door culture (a
>   resistance to regarding social features as first-order effects)** and
>   a horror of censorship (maximizing individual freedom, even when it
>   conflicts with group goals.)

Comment: Is it possible a word was omitted? *open-door culture*, *closed-door culture* and even *revolving-door culture* all make more sense here.

Comment: This article is also published in a book.  The book matches the post here.  According to the errata there are no errors.  http://www.apress.com/9781590595008

Comment: Well I have never heard the term before, but the author was at least helpful enough to tell you what he referring to in the parentheses.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Based on my experience with such things, I would infer something close to “revolving door” – lots of user turnover, and pressure to filter or leave if you don't fit in.

Answer (score 1):

In [the article itself](http://shirky.com/writings/group_user.html), Shirky writes

> And yet, when we poll users about what they actually do with their computers, some form of social interaction always tops the list -- conversation, collaboration, playing games, and so on. The practice of software design is shot through with computer-as-box assumptions, while our actual behavior is closer to computer-as-door, treating the device as an entrance to a social space.

Presumably this treatment of a computer as a door to shared space leads to “door culture”. However it’s not clear to me what the “social features” are and what they are first-order effects **of**. I’m not a sociologist.

Answer (score -1):

To be perfectly frank, it doesn't mean anything. "Open-door culture" and "revolving-door culture" both refer to specific phenomena but a basic "door culture" does not call up any meaning outside of the author's unique usage. If the meaning cannot be determined from the source material then I suggest chalking this up to opaque writing and either sending a letter to the author or writing it off as unknowable.